# SASS Mixin Arguments with specific values

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to check argument in mixins. 
For example, I have a shadow mixin and want to include it (call it) different way in case of its argument.

@mixin shadow($shadow, $position, $color) {
 .....
}

If I pass Top2 it should change only first parameter

```
.box { @include shadow(inset, Top2, #000); } => `box-shadow: inset, 2px 0 0 0, #000`
```

If I pass Bottom2 it should change the parameter to -2px

```
.box { @include shadow(inset, Bottom2, #000); } => `box-shadow: inset, -2px 0 0 0, #000`
```

Comment: I don't believe so, a mixin is a reusable block of css
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_a_mixin

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want exactly ? Can you show us your mixin ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this type.

```
    @mixin box-shadow($values) {
-webkit-box-shadow: $values;
-moz-box-shadow: $values; 
box-shadow: $values;
}
    @mixin box-shadow-inset($inset) {
-webkit-box-shadow: $inset;
-moz-box-shadow: $inset;
      box-shadow: $inset;
}
```